# Four unknown with sum and product given

Tags: linear-algebra

I need help to solve below unknowns $A,B,C,D$ in a proper way.

$$AC=6$$
$$AD+BC=-25$$
$$BD=25$$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Four unknowns, three equations?

Comment: I can eyeball the integer solution $A=2,B=-5,C=3,D=-5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $AC = 6$, $C = \frac{6}{A}$. Similarly, since $BD = 25$, $D = \frac{25}{B}$. So,
$$AD + BC = \frac{25A}{B} + \frac{6B}{A} = -25$$
$$25A^2+6B^2=-25AB.$$
Now just choose any nonzero $B$ and solve for $A$ and you will get a solution. For instance, if $B = 1$, then
$$25A^2+6=-25A \implies 25A^2 +25A +6=0.$$
Using the quadratic formula we get that $A = -0.6$ or $A = -0.4$. Then, we can solve for the rest of the unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

Four equations and three unknowns will usually result is one equation with two unknowns or a one free variable which may be any value and the other three variables dependent upon it.

$A = \frac 6C$ and $B=\frac {25}D$

So $AD + BC= \frac {6D}C + \frac {25C}D = -25$

If $m = \frac CD$ we hav $25m^2+25m + 6 = 0$

So $m =\frac {-25\pm\sqrt{25^2 - 4*6*25}}{50}=\frac{-25\pm 5}{50}=-\frac 25, -\frac 35$

So we can have $C$ be any value (except $0$, of course).  $D=$ either $-\frac 52C$ or $-\frac 53 C$.  $A= \frac 6C$ and $B=$ either $-\frac {10}{C}$ or $-\frac {15}{C}$

Do they have to be integers?

If so then $C=\pm 2,\pm 3$ (Because $C$ divides $6$ and either $10$ or $15$ and either $\frac 52C$ or $\frac 53 C$ is an integer), $A = \pm 3, \pm 2$, and  $D=B= \mp 5$.

Comment: Great Help, Thank you.